# How to get this pseudocode to double a number in a while loop?

Tags: python

[pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXuIW.png)

```
numtodouble=int
result=int
print("")

print("Enter a number you would like to double and press Enter.")
input (numtodouble)
<class 'int'>2
'2'
while numtodouble>0:
    result=numtodouble*2
    print("2 X", numtodouble, "=", result)
    print("")
    print("Enter a number you would like to double and press Enter.")
    input(numtodouble)
    break
print("OK, you entered a value <=0, ending execution.")
```

Does anyone know where I went wrong with my code? I've been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: Why would you include a screenshot of code when you could just copy/paste it?

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? Either way, you should read up on [the correct way to use the `input` method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: @Hamms 3, judging from `print(...)`

Comment: That seems likely, but it's worth noting that `print` can work exactly that same way in python2, whereas the implementation of `input` changed between the two versions

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    # input is stored as num_to_double. the input is cast to an int, and the string in input is the prompt
    num_to_double = int(input("Enter a number you would like to double and press Enter."))
    while num_to_double>0:
        result=num_to_double*2
        # Format puts the arguments into the curly braces in the order given
        print("2 X {} = {}\n".format(num_to_double, result))
        # input is cast to int and stored in num_to_double. The text in the input command is the prompt
        num_to_double =int(input("Enter a number you would like to double and press Enter."))
    # This is otuside the while loop, so this runs when the while loop breaks. The previous break command was making 
    # the code act not as intended
    print("OK, you entered a value <=0, ending execution.")
# This catches if someone inputs a value that is not able to be cast to a string. It's the second half of the Try: 
# Except block.
except ValueError as _:
    print("A not-a-number was supplied")
```

This code is far simplier and does what you're trying to do. I assume you're learning python, so some of these things are not the simplest way to do things, like the format function, but are super useful to learn.

```
num_to_double = 0
result = 0
print("")
num_to_double = int(input("Enter number would you like to double and press enter."))
while num_to_double > 0:
    result = num_to_double * 2
    print("2 X {} = {}".format(num_to_double, result))
    print("")
    num_to_double = int(input("Enter number would you like to double and press enter."))
print("OK< you entered a value <=0, ending execution.")
```

This code is the closest I could do to the pseudocode provided. Declaring variables before they're used here isn't necessary and is messy. It's like the pseudocode wasn't meant to become python. Same with printing blank lines, those should be wrapped into the previous or next print lines.